# AngularJS App not working on github pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github, github-pages

So this is the repository

https://github.com/fredericojesus/mygroceries-angular

and this is the link for github pages

http://fredericojesus.github.io/mygroceries-angular/

For some reason the browser is not getting the files (see console), but they exist so really dunno what's happening, I'm new to github pages, first time trying.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: Greetings, as far as I know, `github.io` only serves static files. So loading external resources (including those on the same domain) won't be fetched. If you can copy paste the contents in your included files in your index.html, it will work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `<base href="/">` in your `index.html`. Then add the folder name to the `libraries` path.

**E.g.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/lib-25ab91c4a2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app-2b5253690c.css">

<script src="js/lib-05ac045750.js"></script>
<script src="js/app-d3af5f3ca4.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to add the right path of your `libraries' directory` (js and css). I will update my answer.

Comment: yes I saw that was wrong because I was trying having all files in the same folder, I got it right again, still not working :S

Comment: sorry it's working, I had to remove the base href again hehe tks dude! a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem without the below answer helped me. Taking off this meta tag made the github page work.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" >
```