# Angular 5 app not displaying on Github pages

Tags: angular, github-pages, angular-cli-ghpages

I created the default Angular app using the CLI like so:

```
ng new ng-test-deploy
```

to test out deploying a dummy app to Github pages. 
I ran through the procedure as defined [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages) which, to summarise, does this:

```
ng build --prod --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY_NAME/"
angular-cli-ghpages
```

After doing that I visited the page and receive a blank page. In the console there are multiple errors regarding loading the files:

[image]

If i check the url of say the `main.bundle.js` I can see that the path is pointing to https://katana24.github.io/main.3188de4880a80d258168.bundle.js
whereas I can load it by adding the repo name into the url like so:
https://katana24.github.io/ng-test-edeploy/main.3188de4880a80d258168.bundle.js

Did I mess up a step?

A previous [questions'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643449/angularjs-app-not-working-on-github-pages) answer suggested removing the `base-href="..."` value but this doesn't make sense to me. So how do I get it to look in the right places?

Comment: Could you add the `index.html` for your app?

Comment: I think you messed up with the base href. Don't put the entire URL there. Only the context "ng-test-deploy".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credit to both @ochs.tobi and @funkizer for their help. So yes, the `base href` was incorrect for the project.

First thing I had to do was to update the `href` in the `index.html` to the name of my project.

After that I needed to rebuild the application for a production environment and only have the project name as the `href`:

```
 ng build --prod --base-href "ng-test-deploy"
```

Then navigating to the site, after say 30 seconds, displayed what I was after.

**EDIT**

After investigating this some more I feel this is a better option. Inside of the `angular-cli.json` you can define different apps for different purposes - perhaps one for production, staging etc. Like so:

```
"apps": [
    { 
      "name": "app-dev",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "app-production",
      "baseHref": "/ng-test-deploy",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Inside each of these objects you can see the `base-href` to whatever you like. Then to build it out, in this case the `app-production` app, do this:

```
ng build --prod --base-href "ng-test-deploy" --app app-production
```

Which will build the target app for production based on its href. Leaving out the base href tag above resulted in the same error as I described above and is needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
<base href="/ng-test-deploy/">
```

This is needed not only for scripts and styles to load, but for router to work properly too.

Comment: I suspected this actually. Will test out soon

Comment: That didn't work. Plus the local stopped working - for obvious reasons

Comment: Got it working now - see my answer. Marking up as this is half the answer