# Deployed my Angular app on GitHub pages but errors coming on website in console

Tags: angular, github, angular-cli-ghpages

I have published my app successfully on GitHub pages, but my website is not displaying anything.

This is my GitHub repository link: https://github.com/chirag299051/Ice-and-Fire

Errors I am getting in console:

```
inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
polyfills.b6b2cd0d4c472ac3ac12.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
scripts.e2cc764d74d6cb8d1c42.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.54e8c9147109b23af744.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
styles.a9b0b1037568d3083749.bundle.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
polyfills.b6b2cd0d4c472ac3ac12.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
scripts.e2cc764d74d6cb8d1c42.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.54e8c9147109b23af744.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
styles.a9b0b1037568d3083749.bundle.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your scripts reside in `https://chirag299051.github.io/Ice-and-Fire` whereas your app is trying to fetch them from `https://chirag299051.github.io/`.

Make it so that you're fetching scripts from `https://chirag299051.github.io/Ice-and-Fire`.

For instance,  `https://chirag299051.github.io/main.54e8c9147109b23af744.bundle.js` should be `https://chirag299051.github.io/Ice-and-Fire/main.54e8c9147109b23af744.bundle.js`.

You can set these paths by building your project with the `--base-href` flag and setting the `<base href>` tag in your `index.html`, [see the documentation for more information.](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

In your cases this results in

```
ng build --base-href=/Ice-and-Fire/
```

and an `index.html` that looks like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/Ice-and-Fire/">
    ...
  </head>
  <body>...</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how do i get the scripts from https://chirag299051.github.io/Ice-and-Fire, I have already specified the path in index.html : <base href="https://chirag299051.github.io/Ice-and-Fire">

Comment: Did you also build the app with `ng build --base-href=/Ice-and-Fire/`?

Comment: Also, I think your `<base href>` should be `<base href="/Ice-and-Fire/">`, see https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag

Comment: Did you push the changes to `gh-pages`? I ask because `base href` is still pointing to `<base href="https://chirag299051.github.io/Ice-and-Fire">`, see https://github.com/chirag299051/Ice-and-Fire/blob/gh-pages/index.html.

Comment: How are you pushing your app to GitHub?

Comment: Setting the correct `base href` should do it, see this question for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092864/angular-5-app-not-displaying-on-github-pages?rq=1